# Добавление файлов в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте подскажите почему не работает код! При мульти апплоуде фотографии каждая должна занаситься в БД ... но не заноситься в чем проблема ? Что стоит изменить в скрипте загрузки фотографии ? Помогите пожалуйста.

```
<?php

foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "uploads/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);
        $actual_image_name = 'uploads/' . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (url) VALUE($actual_image_name)");
    }
}

echo "<h2>Successfully Uploaded Images</h2>";
?>
```

Comment: Форму загрузки файла тоже приложи.

Comment: Insert into tv values('', '', ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при услоавии, что файл дествительно зуагружается, то названия обязательно надо кавычками экранировать

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos VALUES ('$actual_image_name')");
```

а вообще было бы круто включить вывод ошибок...